# Update net.parameters() without .data

Tags: pytorch, autograd

Is there any way to update the net parameters with some other tensors that carry gradients as well?

I want to do something like the following:

```
grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss, net.parameters(), 
                                    create_graph=True) 

for param gi in zip(net.parameters(), grads): 
       param -= eps * gi
```

And I want each param to carry the grad_fn of gi.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by wrapping the whole loop with `torch.no_grad()`:

```
grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss, net.parameters(), create_graph=True) 
with torch.no_grad():
    for param, gi in zip(net.parameters(), grads):
        param -= eps*gi
```

Alternatively you can use the in-place [`copy_()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.copy_) on `param`'s `data` property:

```
grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss, net.parameters(), create_graph=True) 
for param, gi in zip(net.parameters(), grads): 
    param.data.copy_(param.data - eps*gi)
```

As far as I have tested, both methods update the parameters the same way.

---

I haven't found any way to copy the `grad_fn` property though. As a workaround you could copy to `gi` instead of `param`, this will overwrite the values of `grads` with what would have been the new parameters of the model:

```
grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss, net.parameters(), create_graph=True) 
for param, gi in zip(net.parameters(), grads): 
    gi.data.copy_(param.data - eps*gi)
```

In case you need to keep `grads` unmodified, just clone it before the entering the loop.

Comment: Thanks. But the updated params do not carry the grad_fn of grads. That's my problem. Their grad_fn is requires_grad = True, while grads have a different one.